# FBSDK secure network request failed iOS9

Tags: ios, facebook, ssl, sdk, ios9

We were getting App Transport Security errors in the simulator (Xcode 7 running on OSX 10.10.5). We implemented FB guidelines for iOS9.

FB graph api invoked was that based on SDK v.3.24.

We had added the Facebook SDK, successfully compiled with Bit, after inserting the required App Transport Security exceptions into the App info.plist file.

The errors looked like those the Facebook documentation in lack of ATS info.plist configuration,
i. e.:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2015-09-21 15:25:20.862 flirtop[41983:2110078] FBSDKLog: WARNING: FBSDK secure network request failed. Please verify you have configured your app for Application Transport Security compatibility described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9
2015-09-21 15:25:21.131 flirtop[41983:2110592] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2015-09-21 15:25:21.132 flirtop[41983:2110078] FBSDKLog: WARNING: FBSDK secure network request failed. Please verify you have configured your app for Application Transport Security compatibility described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9
2015-09-21 15:25:21.135 flirtop[41983:2110078] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : 
    1 : 
)}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fec5d300b40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : 
    1 : 
)}, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., --- SNIP --
```

our plist, with App Id omitted, was the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.fwlab.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>OMITTED</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>OMITTED</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Flirtop</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>graph.facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Since you already have `facebook.com` and includes subdomains `on`, have you tried simply removing `graph.facebook.com` to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, that was not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. 
The info.plist which got copied into the App bundle was not the right one.
This works without the graph.facebook.com entry, which is not necessary.

It became apparent when I tried using Facebook Login and it complained that the url fbauth2 was not present in the info.plist file.

Incidentally, the correct ending part of the Info.plist is the following, which includes the correct complete Facebook SDK setup.
NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = False is enough for FB graph api to work.

As FB servers are not under my control, probably I should use  NSThirdPartyException, however the following setup works.

```
-- SNIP --
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I have the plist file including fbauth2; the app correctly login and logout; however I still get the following `error: [4102:149576] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"`Any idea why?

Comment: That's quite probably a totally unrelated problem. In my case I did receive an error ("An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."), not a null error. 

After investigating that the issue is not about some allocation issue, if you still have trouble, you should document your passages and open another question.

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your Info.plist file and the errors will go away. If you don't understand the XML code, see the screenshot below.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Screenshot from Xcode that might help you better than the pure XML:**
[image: Here is a screenshot from Xcode that might help you better than the pure XML below.]

Comment: Thanks, lad. Did it swiftly.

Comment: not working for me. I am trying to fetch user details using Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below link, you need to do some update in info.plist

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to “Allow Arbitrary Loads”, by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `YES`:

[image]

> An optional Boolean value that, when set to YES, disables App
>   Transport Security (ATS) for any domains for which you do not reenable
>   ATS by using an exception domain dictionary.

More info [here>>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)